# Android logon to any asp website

Tags: java, android, asp.net, authentication, http-post

EDITED: [Java httpPost into .asp form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746375/java-httppost-into-asp-form)

I am making an application that will display some information from the website, which is .asp, to access some of the data I must login. How can I post my credentials(login, password) to the server and get the page in return. I also think that there a lot of redirects on the way, when I login. I have no idea about asp. What I am doing, I am just posting the username, password to the server and I can retrieve the source code of that page with my posted information in the right place. But what do I do next?
I thought That there could be one code snippet that can be used with any .asp website engine.

EDIT: Ok, page code is received
Authentication form has been of IIS type.

when specifuing nameValuePairs use html input (name, value) pairs.

Login form:

```
<form method="post" id="form1" name="form1" action="">
<input id="txtUser" name="txtUser" type="text" size="13" value="" />
<input id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" type="password" size="13" value="" />
<input id="BLogin" name="BLogin" type="submit" value="Log in"  />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkSave" name="chkSave"/> 
</form>
```

some JAVA:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("WEBSITE WITH LOGIN PAGE (Ex: www.qwerty.asd/login.asp)");
try {
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtUser", "YOUR LOGIN NAME"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtPassword", "YOUR PASSWORD"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("BLogin", "Log in"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
// Execute HTTP Post Request
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
entity = response.getEntity();
System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
if (entity != null) {
entity.consumeContent();
}
System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
System.out.println("None");
} else {
for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i));
// httpclient.getCookieStore().addCookie(cookies.get(i));
}
}
```

Getting headers:

```
Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
                for(int i=0; i<headers.length; i++){
                    //System.out.println(headers[i]);
                    Header h = headers[i];
                    System.out.println(h.getName());
                    System.out.println(h.getValue());
                }
```

Proceed to any other page within same service:

```
HttpPost request2 = new HttpPost(
                    "www.qwerty.asd/information.asp");

            response = httpclient.execute(request2);

            String responseBody2 = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            //System.out.println(responseBody2);

            if (entity != null) {
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
```

For Android Webview to display the web page:

```
        WebView.loadData(responseBody2, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: @Boris, do you want to display the page after login as it is or you want to extract some data from that page and then display it ?

Comment: @Santosh, for the beginning I would like to display a page that comes after logon screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.asp has nothing to do with Android directly.

You are looking to make a standard HTTP REST request using a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Also, here is a page that includes many common tasks in Android as well as links to many tutorials, articles and code samples : http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html

EDIT: Many might say use a standard alert dialog with a login button BUT I do not believe in the alert dialogs because they have issues. To see an example, create a simple dialog that does nothing and change the screen orientation... it might seem fine but if you look at the LogCat you will see it leaks the activity.

Therefore, I recommend creating a regular Activity and using the android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" in the activity tag in your manifest to make the activity look like a dialog.

Comment: I mean I need to have something like an AlertDialog that will ask user for a username and password and post this information to the server

Comment: Your answer is inappropriate for the question I have posted. I am not asking about alertDialog - that is a fact. My issue turns around http client and http post

Comment: Then you failed to read the first part of my answer... if you just want source code then pay someone otherwise if you truly would like to know pay attention... You could use an alert dialog (I recommend using an activity) and you would send that data to your site using a normal REST request. Then using a WebView you can display any web pages AFTER login... Again I will repeat... .asp has NOTHING to do with Android.

Comment: The form method was post, so I have used HttpPost to send my values

Answer (score 0):

Boris,
        Give you problem, please try following.

1. From the browser, check all the URLs and status codes that browser receives after you login and returns the page you need. For this you will need some browser plugin like YSlow or FireBug (http://getfirebug.com/). Install any of these plugin and look at the request/response.
2. Now please have brief look at apache's http-client library. Check out the URL http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient .
3. This library is very powerful and it is capable of achieving anything a browser can achieve (with respect to interaction with http servers).
4. Now from #1 above you have the pattern of the request/response and http-client lib which can achieve this programmatically.

Comment: Have achieved it in an easier way

Comment: Nice. Can you put the details in brief over here ?

Comment: Yes, just put some. Now must combine a couple websites into one by operating with cookies