# Android HttpPost session

Tags: java, android, http, cookies, http-post

After executing HttpPost onto server with login information and receiving right response I would like to get another page. In this case, should I use cookies in order to continue my session or is there any other way of doing that?

**EDIT:**
The way i managed this task was to utilize the same httpClient for the new requests.

```
public CustomHttpClient() {
        params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, true);
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        // customRedirectHandler = new CustomRedirectHandler();
        // client.setRedirectHandler(customRedirectHandler);
    }
```

after that executing a method on the server

```
public String httpGetViewstate(String url){
...
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

                request.setURI(new URI(url));
                response = client.execute(request);
...
}
```

and a new method execution

```
public String httpGet(String url) {
...
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        response = client.execute(request);
...
}
```

and then closing the connection

```
public void shutDownClient() {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: Do you really think that this explanation is clearer than the one you gave in the comments of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746375/java-httppost-into-asp-form)? Please describe **in detail** what you want to happen.

Comment: =) I am accumulating information step by step, not everything at once

Comment: What i want to do is just to login to the remote server, retrieve a page, delete some stuff from it and display already to the user, but the only thing the user will do is just to enter his login information, so everything will be happenning on the background.

Comment: but unless we know what you're trying to do, we can't give good answers. Don't let us guess at what you want to achieve!

Comment: the biggest problem is that i am very bad in distributed invokation

Answer (score 0):

use HTMLUnit. (http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) It´s really simple and fowerful. If not just set your cookie which you got from the login response to new page requests.

```
 urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieString);
```

Comment: I decided to continue with the httpClient, but it is possible to do the same task with the UrlCOnnection. It is just that httpClient provides following redirects function(and not only), which was very usefull for me