# Catch POST from webview in android

Tags: android, http, post, android-webview

I have a simple page in html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "formular.html" method = "POST">
Name<inpt type = "text"></br>
Surname<inpt type = "text"></br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this page I have in webview. This is any possibility to catch in application when user click on send button. I want to catch this POST. How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean catch? you want to use the post parameters entered?

Comment: no no, I want show android dialog, when I click on send button

Comment: I think you need to use AJAX somehow, and have a service listening for it. I'd like to see the answer fleshed out.

Comment: This [Android bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9122) might be related. See also [How to intercept POST data in an android webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584597/how-to-intercept-post-data-in-an-android-webview?rq=1) and [Intercept POST requests in a WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954049/intercept-post-requests-in-a-webview)