# Getting callback from payment gateway in webview

Tags: android, http, post, webview, intentfilter

I am using [Atom](http://www.atomtech.in/) Payment Gateway for payments in my Android app. But this provider doesn't have an SDK for mobile platforms, also I cannot choose another provider because my client has been using Atom PG for their website for a long time.

So to make it work, I am now trying to call it in a webview in my app. All goes well until the last step except that I am not able to get the response from the PG upon completion of transaction.

As per their documentation:

> After the completion of the transaction, the response will be posted back to the url provided by the merchant.

I already tried setting the `return url` to my reverse domain name and then setting an `intent-filter` but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there any method by which I can get the `response` that the PG "posts back" to the return url?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, can you tell me how you fixed this?

Comment: We ended up using a different provider. Their model was not suitable for mobile applications. It may be solved by using @chiragjn's suggestion, but it would not be pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea,
On getting the post request on your return url, you can parse that response and then via javascript send that to the [JavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html) linked to your WebView in the app

Intercepting POST data has been discussed:

[How to intercept POST data in an android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584597/how-to-intercept-post-data-in-an-android-webview)

[Intercept POST requests in a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954049/intercept-post-requests-in-a-webview)

Try this project : https://github.com/KeejOow/android-post-webview

Comment: Yeah that would require a server right? is there any way to catch that POST data in the webview itself? now it just redirects to the return url.

Comment: Is there any workaround to get the Post data (Form data received as request parameter) in the callback URL opened in the browser itself ?