# Populating gmail login form in webview with dynamic values?

Tags: android, forms, webview, gmail

I want populate gmail login form in WebView with some dynamic username and password values.How can we do it? As I know we can get the data from html to android using [javascript](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html). But I want send the data from android to websites which are not in our control (like gmail,yahoomail). Help me..

Comment: the best way in my opinion is to post the data from application, using httpClient. Here is an example i used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746375/java-httppost-into-asp-form  | P.S. asp form in there is just an example

Comment: we should load the gmail in WebView with  values which we provide through our android program

Comment: So you don't want to perform any log in, just populate and leave them in the input boxes?

Comment: yes,we leave it log in action to the user

Answer (score 0):

You can input values with javascript as well, for example:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:gaia_loginform.Email.value=\"" + email + "\"");
webView.loadUrl("javascript:gaia_loginform.Passwd.value=\"" + password + "\"");
```

I'm not sure how consistent the Google login page is between services (this was from gmail), but as long as you know the form name and field name, you should be good.

Comment: hey can you give more clarity?where can we load gmail(www.gmail.com)?

Comment: not only javascript is any other way to put the data into WebView fomrs in android